# Chaining methods in factory-method

Tags: java, spring

Is it possible to chain methods in `factory-method` in spring to create beans. For example, I have the following API:

```
SomeObject.builder().build();
```

Is there some way I can create this bean in spring XML config directly without creating 2 beans? For example,

```
<bean id="fooBar" class="com.foo.bar.SomeObject" factory-method="builder().build"/>
```

Note: The `SomeObject.builder()` call returns a `SomeObjectBuilder` object(`private static class` within `SomeObject`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that. You just specify a single method (even without the brackets). But in `SomeObject` class you can create a static method that does that for you. For example:

```
static SomeObject newFactoryMethod(){
    return builder().build();
}
```

And add it to the XML:

```
<bean id="fooBar" class="com.foo.bar.SomeObject" factory-method="newFactoryMethod"/>
```

Comment: This code is in some external jar I can't access. I think I'll have to create another bean only first.